# Creating UIImage with renderingMode in Swift

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift

In objectiveC I would do this

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]   imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

but in Swift I have tried all alternatives like this, without success

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"myImage.png").imageWithRenderingMode(renderingMode: AlwaysOriginal)
```

It shows an error: **use of unresolved identifier 'AlwaysOriginal'**

How do I do that?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

that would be the proper syntax:

---

(for **Swift 3.x** or **Swift 4**)

```
var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

---

(for **Swift 2.x**)

```
var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage.png").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

but you can use this 'shortcut' as well:

```
var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage.png").imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: ahhh, fantastic. You pass a kind of object that has a enum value. I thought I just needed to pass the enum value. THANKS!

Comment: uggh, I wish Xcode's code complete would be just a bit smarter, e.g. if you type ".imageWithRenderingMode" it really should predict ".withRenderingMode"...would save countless google searches