# Change Color of unselected tabbar icon

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have changed the selected color of tab bar icon buy giving user defined runtime Attribute  "tintColor". now i need to change unselected tab bar icon color can any body tell me the "user defined runtime Attribute" key word for it?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue and ended up using original images that has the desired color for `unselected` state and when any item is selected we applied the `tintColor`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i have tried it but it also give gray color

Comment: You should mark your images' `renderingMode` as `AlwaysOriginal` ([learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24145221/2177402))

Comment: @IslamQ. i've tried it but didn't succeed