# Creating an image with UIImage.renderingMode()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some issues initializing an image in my code. I'm trying to change its tintColor property when the cell it sits in is highlighted like so:

```
iconImageView.tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
```

And to do so I'm initializing the image with the following line:

```
iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.renderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImage.RenderingMode'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, try with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145221/creating-uiimage-with-renderingmode-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

The 'renderingMode' is a read-only property of UIImage.

Creates and returns a new image object with the specified rendering mode. 
You can use:

```
open func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage
```

Code snippet:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView.init()
let image = UIImage.init(named: "name")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
imageView.image = image
```

Answer (score 0):

`renderingMode` specifies the possible rendering modes for an image.

`withRenderingMode(_:)` creates and returns a new UIImage object with the specified rendering mode.

So, you need to use `withRenderingMode(_:)` which is a function versus `renderingMode` which is a property.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
iconImageView.image.setImage(image, for: .normal)
iconImageView.image.tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
```